# Collision works with the top, but not the bottom

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a rectangle in my game testing environment and I was trying to make it collide with it. The collision works with the top since I made the proper code. However, I have had lots of difficulty trying to make it collide with the bottom portion of the rectangle.

I have already tried changing the x and y and swapping them out. I have also tried changing the comparing functions. What I have thought of doing was to switch them completely, but I don't think that would work either.

```js
        var canvas = document.getElementById("gametester");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        
        var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
        var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

    rectWidth = 100;
       rectHeight = 50;
       var redX = canvasWidth / 2 - rectWidth / 2; 
       var redY = canvasHeight / 2 - rectHeight / 2; 
       var redDx = 0;
       var redDy = 0;
       var speed = 2;

      
       rectWidth = 100;
       rectHeight = 50;
       var blueX = canvasWidth / 2 - rectWidth / 2; 
       var blueY = canvasHeight / 2 - rectHeight / 2; 
       var blueDx = 0;
       var blueDy = 0;
       var speed = 2;
       var rectTwoColour = "blue";


        
        var dx = 0;
        var dy = 0;
        var speed = 2;

        function rectangle(x, y, w, h, c) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
            ctx.fillStyle = c;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
  
  
  var rightPressed = false;
  var leftPressed = false;
  var upPressed = false;
  var downPressed = false;
  
  
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
  
  
  function keyDownHandler(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      rightPressed = true;
     } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      leftPressed = true;
     } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      upPressed = true;
     } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      downPressed = true;
     }
    }
  
    function keyUpHandler(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      rightPressed = false;
     } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      leftPressed = false;
     } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      upPressed = false;
     } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      downPressed = false;
     }
    }

   function collision(){
       
           var collide = false;
          
           if (blueY>=redY && blueY <= redY + rectHeight){
         
           if (redX + rectWidth >= blueX && redX + rectWidth <= blueX + rectWidth){
                   collide = true;    
             blueX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasWidth - rectWidth));
             blueY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasHeight - rectWidth));
               }
              
               if (redX>=blueX && redX <= blueX + rectWidth){
                   collide = true;
    blueX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasWidth - rectWidth));
             blueY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasHeight - rectWidth));
               }
           }
     
  
     
           
           


           return collide
       }




        function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            
   rectangle(redX, redY, rectWidth, rectHeight, 'red')
   rectangle(blueX, blueY, rectWidth, rectHeight, rectTwoColour)
   if (rightPressed==true) {
      redDx = speed;
         } else if (leftPressed==true) {
      redDx = -speed;
         } else if (upPressed==true) {
      redDy = -speed;
         } else if (downPressed==true) {
      redDy = speed
         }
   if (rightPressed==false && leftPressed==false && upPressed==false && downPressed == false){
            redDx = 0;
            redDy = 0;
            }
   redX = redX + redDx;
            redY = redY + redDy; 
   if (redX > canvasWidth - rectWidth){
            redX = canvasWidth - rectWidth;
            }
   if (redY > canvasHeight - rectHeight){
            redY = canvasHeight - rectHeight;
            }
   if (redY<0){
            redY = 0
            }
   if (redX<0){
            redX = 0
            }
   
   
           collided = collision();
          
           
           if (collided == true){
               rectTwoColour = "purple";
             } else {
               rectTwoColour = "blue";
            }
   

          

            }

        setInterval(draw, 14);
```

```css
   canvas {
            border-width: 6.2px;
            border-color: #FF0000;
        }
```

```html
    <canvas id="gametester" width="560" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check 4 sides, at the moment you're only checking 3.
Hint: look at the first if inside collision function and see if it's missing something

```
if (
   blueY >= redY && blueY <= redY + rectHeight || // north side
   ... // south side
)
```

If you can't solve it check this https://jsfiddle.net/dn6ar45x/1/

Comment: ohhhh, thank you. Didn't notice that at first, but now I understand.

Comment: Hope it solved your problem. Mark the answer as solved if it did

Answer (score 1):

Your rectangle collision detection is incorrect it should be as follows

```
function collision() {

  var collide = false;

  if (blueX < redX + rectWidth &&
    blueX + rectWidth > redX &&
    blueY < redY + rectHeight &&
    blueY + rectHeight > redY) {
    // collision detected!
    collide = true;
    blueX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasWidth - rectWidth));
    blueY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasHeight - rectWidth));
  }
  return collide
}
```

See [2D rectangle collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("gametester");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

rectWidth = 100;
rectHeight = 50;
var redX = canvasWidth / 2 - rectWidth / 2;
var redY = canvasHeight / 2 - rectHeight / 2;
var redDx = 0;
var redDy = 0;
var speed = 2;


rectWidth = 100;
rectHeight = 50;
var blueX = canvasWidth / 2 - rectWidth / 2;
var blueY = canvasHeight / 2 - rectHeight / 2;
var blueDx = 0;
var blueDy = 0;
var speed = 2;
var rectTwoColour = "blue";



var dx = 0;
var dy = 0;
var speed = 2;

function rectangle(x, y, w, h, c) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = c;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}


var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;


document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);


function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = false;
  }
}

function collision() {

  var collide = false;

  if (blueX < redX + rectWidth &&
    blueX + rectWidth > redX &&
    blueY < redY + rectHeight &&
    blueY + rectHeight > redY) {
    // collision detected!
    collide = true;
    blueX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasWidth - rectWidth));
    blueY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvasHeight - rectWidth));
  }
  return collide
}




function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  rectangle(redX, redY, rectWidth, rectHeight, 'red')
  rectangle(blueX, blueY, rectWidth, rectHeight, rectTwoColour)
  if (rightPressed == true) {
    redDx = speed;
  } else if (leftPressed == true) {
    redDx = -speed;
  } else if (upPressed == true) {
    redDy = -speed;
  } else if (downPressed == true) {
    redDy = speed
  }
  if (rightPressed == false && leftPressed == false && upPressed == false && downPressed == false) {
    redDx = 0;
    redDy = 0;
  }
  redX = redX + redDx;
  redY = redY + redDy;
  if (redX > canvasWidth - rectWidth) {
    redX = canvasWidth - rectWidth;
  }
  if (redY > canvasHeight - rectHeight) {
    redY = canvasHeight - rectHeight;
  }
  if (redY < 0) {
    redY = 0
  }
  if (redX < 0) {
    redX = 0
  }


  collided = collision();


  if (collided == true) {
    rectTwoColour = "purple";
  } else {
    rectTwoColour = "blue";
  }




}

setInterval(draw, 14);
```

```css
canvas {
  border-width: 6.2px;
  border-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gametester" width="560" height="300"></canvas>
```

Hope this helps!